# Hot to handle c++11 lambda with both this pointer captured and calling convention specified

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

With VC2012, the compiler will automatically handle the calling convention when lambda function is used with no capture list.
e.g.

```
EnumWindows([](HWND, LPARAM){ return TRUE; }, 0); // compile with no problem
```

But when I put the this pointer to the capture list, it failed to compile.
e.g.

```
EnumWindows([this](HWND, LPARAM){ return my_class_member_function(); }, 0); // error
```

Could someone let me know if there is a way to call the member function within the lambda function?

Thanks, Miles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only lambdas that do not capture anything can be converted to function pointers and this API only accepts pointers.

What you can do is to keep the lambda stateless, and transfer `this` through `lparam`:

```
EnumWindows(
         [](HWND, LPARAM lparam){
             return reinterpret_cast<Your_Class*>(lparam)->my_class_member_function();
         },
         reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
```

Comment: The solution is cool and tricky, but not generic. Maybe next version of c++ spec/impl will handle it more properly and smoothly?

Comment: @MilesChen, it is already possible, when defining new API to accept `std::function` or any callable type (with a template). But with function pointer based interfaces you need to pass state in a way supported by that interface.

Comment: More directly, there has been [a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3574.html) to add the ability to have stateful function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the calling convention. The problem is that capturing lambdas don't offer a conversion to pointer-to-function, so you can't pass such a lambda where a pointer to function is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Only stateless lambda function could be decayed to function pointer. When you've added state(by capturing `this`) you don't have this ability any longer.